# In Python, my String Comparisons are ALWAYS Coming Back False:

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

For some reason, all of my "if's" and "elif's" come back true no matter what

```
nyornj = raw_input("select ny or nj please")
newyork="NY" or "nj"
newjersey="NJ" or "nj"
if nyornj==newyork:
    print "New York was input"
if nyornj==newjersey:
    print "New Jersey was input"
```

Nothing seems to be working, any ideas why this would always come back true?

Comment: It's short circuiting to the first condition so it's always comparing to `"NY" or "NJ"`, you could've tested this if you'd printed out `newyork` and `newjersey`, anyway it makes more sense to uppercase or lowercase your input and test against a single value

Comment: ah I see, is there any way to not have this happen but keep the two pairs of "or's"?

Comment: Why do you need `or`? just uppercase or lowercase every thing and test against a single str representation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing with two different value, use str.lower() to convert to all lowercase and then compare.

```
nyornj = raw_input("select ny or nj please")
newyork="ny"
newjersey="nj"
if nyornj.lower()==newyork:
    print "New York was input"
if nyornj.lower()==newjersey:
    print "New Jersey was input"
```

Comment: returns:

    SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: edited, should work now